# Is encrypting with private key instead of signing a bad idea?

Tags: encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I am using a local URL scheme to submit a payload to the client when a user clicks a link and have to make sure that this is only used in my specific web application.
So I am using a key pair, encrypting the payload on the server using the private key, generating a link that the protocol handler on the client can decrypt using the public key, verifying that the payload should be processed.

So is it less secure to send a private-key-encrypted payload instead of a cleartext payload plus signature (and if yes, why)?

Comment: Encryption does not stop a malicious party from tampering with the payload. They can't read it, but they can change it. It's unclear what you're trying to guard against exactly.

Comment: Also encrypting the payload with the private key makes no sense. That means that anyone with the public key can decrypt it, which defeats the point of having encrypted it... I'm not even sure any encryption algorithms support such a pointless operation. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81760/what-happens-when-encrypting-with-private-key

Comment: I want to make sure that no one else can generate links (or use iframes on webpages) that send valid commands to the client. Just like signing my commands but without sending the payload PLUS a signature.

Comment: You want a signature. A signature prevents someone from tampering with the payload. Encryption does not prevent someone from tampering with a payload, or making up their own payload.

Comment: I know but my question is if/why it's less secure to send encrypted payload instead of cleartext payload plus signature.

Comment: It's entirely insecure. Like I have said many times, encryption does not stop someone from changing your payload, and such a change might not be detected. If you engineer things such that the change definitely can be detected, congrats you've invented signing (but badly). See "EXT. HURTLING THROUGH SPACE - CONTINUOUS" in [this article](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2009/july/if-youre-typing-the-letters-a-e-s-into-your-code-youre-doing-it-wrong/), although the whole thing is well worth a read.

Comment: @canton7 so you say that it's possible to generate a link that contains a valid command when decrypted with the public key, without knowing the private key?

Comment: *Especially* since the key doing the decryption is public. An attacker has unlimited offline tries to come up with a payload that, when decrypted with the public key (and the attacker knows what the key is), says what the attacker wants it to say. The private key is almost irrelevant. It will not take someone long at all to invent an encrypted payload which says exactly what they want it to say.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I've been saying all along! Encryption **does not** stop someone from tampering with an encrypted payload, to make it say different things when decrypted (or inventing an entirely new payload which says what they want when decrypted). The fact that you've made the decryption key public makes it even easier (although as the article I linked explains, it was fairly easy to begin with)

Comment: The article seems not to even mention asymmetric crypto...

Comment: The entire article is about AES. It's even in the title ><

Comment: Also see [how Amazon do this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html)

Comment: If you think that AES is asymmetric I better wait for someone else, but thank you anyway.

Comment: I never said that AES was asymmetric. I said the entire article was about AES. My point is still that encryption doesn't stop someone from tampering with the payload - it doesn't matter what keys are used to encrypt or decrypt that payload.

Comment: @canton7: But why are you posting an article about AES on my question about asymmetric crypto?
Also wouldn't the "unlimited offline tries" also apply to signing? You have unlimited offline tries to come up with a matching signature but it would take like forever in both cases.

Comment: Because it's an eye-opener that you can meddle around with an encrypted payload and make meaningful changes to the the decrypted plaintext. The point about a signature is that you've got to take a particular plaintext, and produce a signature which matches that plaintext and also matches the public key, fighting against a scheme which was specifically designed to prevent this. With your scheme, an attacker can make the ciphertext *whatever they want*, the only proviso is that some significant bit of it is decrypted to the right thing, fighting against a scheme not intended to prevent this.

Comment: Do you actually have an asymmetric encryption algorithm which supports encryption using the private key and decryption using the public key?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57513954/1820553), too.

Comment: Thanks, you all already convinced me to use the conventional way to achieve the required result instead of trying to be smart just to save some bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that there are other Stack Exchange sites that answer this question very well:

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2123/rsa-encryption-with-private-key-and-decryption-with-a-public-key

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11879/is-encrypting-data-with-a-private-key-dangerous

I should have searched a little bit longer before asking.

Comment: It's important to highlight one of the answers given there, which says that signing encrypts the hash of the payload, which is different to simply encrypting the payload. In the latter an attacker gets very fine control over what is encrypted, but in the former they don't.

Comment: If we are talking about RSA, we use don't use RSA for encryption. We can use RSA for key exchange, but DHKE is preferable even ECDHKE better. In any case, RSA should not be used without proper padding. If you still want to use for encryption you should use PKCS#1.5 padding or OAEP padding shemes. For the signature RSA-PSS is your choice.

Comment: I ended up with `BASE64( GZIP( SIGN( PAYLOAD ) + PAYLOAD ) )`

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is signing!

*Encrypting* is when a payload is being concealed with one’s **public key** and later decrypted with a **private key**. When I want to send you a secret message, I will take your public key (because I know it) and encrypt my message. This will make sure that **only you** can decrypt it with your **private key**.

*Signing* works vice versa. If during encryption I want to make sure that only you can decrypt me message, with signing I want to make sure that all recipients of the message can be sure in its authenticity. If you encrypt something with your private (*signing*), anyone with your public key can decrypt it and verify its sender.

In your case, if you just want to prove your identity (like certificates, jwt tokens, etc.), you would need to use signing methods. If you want to transfer payload securely, use encryption.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I changed my question to be more specific. I know that what I want is signing but payload plus signature is very long for a link that's why I asked this question.

Comment: @Anatol Some signing schemes are small. Look at what Amazon AWS do when signing a link to an S3 bucket for example.

Comment: That's all true but does not really answer my question. I know that I should sign the payload but asked if encrypting with the private key is less secure than signing with the private key since the identity is proved in both ways. If you could change your answer to cover that question I will be glad to accept it (after some upvotes).

Comment: Or is it just a wording thing and you are saying that what I do is actually signing and therefore secure even if the payload is transferred encrypted instead of cleartext plus signed/encrypted hash?